# Does order in Modifier (Jetpack Compose) matter?

Tags: android

I've just started learning Android and faced unexpected (for me) results. I've a code with using Jetpack Compose (from Google Tutorial):

```
@Composable
fun SingleQuadrant(
    title: String,
    description: String,
    backGroundColor: Color,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    Column (
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(backGroundColor)
            .padding(16.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ){
        Text(
            text = title,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 16.dp),
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )
        Text(
            text = description,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Justify
        )
    }
}
```

And it looks like:

[image]

When I change `.padding(16.dp)` with `background` lines like:

```
modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
            .background(backGroundColor)
```

It will look like this:

[image]

Why this is happening and empty white areas appear? Does order in `Modifier` really matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, order matters and you can read a little bit more [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers?hl=en#order-modifier-matters), even tho it may not be enough.

If I had to think about what's happening in your case I would say the following (Keep in my mind that I'm still learning quite a bit about compose but this could still help):

**First Case**

```
     modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(backGroundColor)
        .padding(16.dp)
```

1. The first thing we're saying is that our column must occupy all the
   space available.
2. The second one is that, while it occupies the full space, we want this
   whole space to have a certain color as background.
3. Only after we've painted the background, we can then apply the padding so
   that the text appears as it does.

**Second Case**

```
     modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(16.dp)
        .background(backGroundColor)
```

1. There we start in the same way, so we required that the column
   occupies all the space available.
2. The second thing that we do is apply the padding, so from now on we limit
   the area on which modifier functions will take effect because of this
   padding.
3. And, at last, we paint the background but our effects will be limited to
   region that we defined when we applied the previous functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, order does matter if you used the padding first, then other attributes/properties take its as margin.